# can I replace a string in two different files with one command?

Tags: linux, command-line, files, find

I have a directory that contains some subdirectories. I know there are two types of files, such as `*A*.txt` and `*B*.txt`, contain an "**oldString**" under that directory. I want to replace them with a "**newString**". Can I do this in one command? That is can I add the `"*B*.txt"` somewhere in this command:

```
find . -type f -name "*A*.txt" -exec sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' {} \;
```

Comment: So... what you're really asking is how to match multiple `-name` patterns in a `find` command?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*A*.txt" -o -name "*B*.txt" \) \
  -exec sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' {} +
```

(here also using `+` instead of `;` to avoid running one `sed` invocation per file; also has the benefit of returning a non-zero exit status if *any* of the `sed` invocations return with a non-zero exit status).

Comment: if I add "-path", can I use the -o there:  find . -type f \( -name "*A*.txt" -o -name "*B*.txt" \) \( -path "oneFolder" -o -path "anotherFolder" \)  -exec sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' {} +

Answer (score 2):

If it really is **just *one* letter**, you can do this:

```
find . -type f -name "*[AB]*.txt" -exec sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' {} \;
```

To be totally clear, this will only work if using a single letter as a match.

Comment: It should be noted though that that approach only works with single-character patterns (there's no equivalent to match on `*foo*.txt` or `*bar*.txt` for instance).

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `find`, you could use `-regex` instead of `-name`, and do something like

```
find . -type -f -regextype egrep -regex "(.*A.*|.*B.*)\.txt" -exec sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' {} \;
```

**Note** that if the pattern can also appear in the directory path to the files, the regular expression needs to be modified (as per @StéphaneChazelas' comment) to be

```
-regex ".*(A|B)[^/]*\.txt"
```

to exclude anything where a `/` occurs after the patterns.

You can check if the regular expression type `egrep` is available using

```
find -regextype help
```

Comment: `-regex` matches on the full path, so it would match on a `./AFTER/foo.txt` for instance. You'd need `-regex '.*/[^/]*(A|B)[^/]*\.txt'` for the `A`/`B` to only be looked for in the file's name.

Comment: `-regex '.*(A|B)[^/]*\.txt'` should be enough.